# How to create tzinfo when I have UTC offset?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one timezone's offset from UTC in seconds (`19800`) and also have it in string format  - `+0530`.

How do I use them to create a `tzinfo` instance? I looked into `pytz`, but there I could only find APIs that take timezone name as input.

Answer (score 48):

With Python 3.2 or higher, you can do this using the builtin datetime library:

```
import datetime
datetime.timezone(-datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30))
```

To solve your specific problem, you could use this regex pattern:

```
sign, hours, minutes = re.match('([+\-]?)(\d{2})(\d{2})', '+0530').groups()
sign = -1 if sign == '-' else 1
hours, minutes = int(hours), int(minutes)

tzinfo = datetime.timezone(sign * datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes))
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 3, 9, 45, tzinfo=tzinfo)
```

Comment: OMG THIS is the answer  I have been looking everywhere for. like why do all the posts and documentation make it so complicated. There had to be some way to just specify the offset

Comment: I appreciate that the currently most popular answer predates this one, but this one should really be the accepted answer.  @AppleGrew, are you still around to mark it?

Answer (score 38):

If you can, take a look at the excellent [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) package instead of implementing this yourself.

Specifically, [tzoffset](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f). It's a fixed offset `tzinfo` instance initialized with `offset`, given in seconds, which is what you're looking for.

**Update**

Here's an example. Be sure to run `pip install python-dateutil` first.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

# First create the tzinfo object
tzlocal = tz.tzoffset('IST', 19800)

# Now add it to a naive datetime
local = naive.replace(tzinfo=tzlocal)

# Or convert another timezone to it
utcnow = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
now = utcnow.astimezone(tzlocal)
```

I looked up the name `IST` [from here](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php). The name can really be anything. Just be careful if you deviate, since if you use code that relies on the name, it could lead to bugs later on.

By the way, if you have the timezone name upfront, and your operating system supports it, you can use [gettz](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-b79630fbbda87af6d6d121737510fd7ea5aeea97) instead:

```
# Replace the above with this
tzlocal = tz.gettz('IST')
```

Comment: This solution requires a third-party library, and a zone name—neither of which should be needed.  See [Turtles Are Cute's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37097784/4877269).

Answer (score 22):

Python Standard Library (8.1.6) says that :

- *tzinfo is an abstract base class*
- *the datetime module does not supply any concrete subclasses of tzinfo*
- *you need to derive a concrete subclass, and (at least) supply implementations of the standard tzinfo methods needed by the datetime methods you use*
- *a concrete subclass of tzinfo may need to implement the following methods ... If in doubt, simply implement all of them*

  - tzinfo.utcoffset(self, dt) : return offset of local time from UTC, in minutes east of UTC
  - tzinfo.dst(self, dt) : return the daylight saving time (DST) adjustment, in minutes east of UTC, or None if DST information isn’t known
  - tzinfo.tzname(self, dt) : return the time zone name corresponding to the datetime object dt, as a string

All that means that you will have to provide your own implementation for the tzinfo. For example :

```py
class UTC0530(datetime.tzinfo):
    """tzinfo derived concrete class named "+0530" with offset of 19800"""
    # can be configured here
    _offset = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 19800)
    _dst = datetime.timedelta(0)
    _name = "+0530"
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__class__._offset
    def dst(self, dt):
        return self.__class__._dst
    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__class__._name
```

Usage :

```
tz = UTC0530()
d = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
d.isoformat()
```

output :

```
2015-01-27T20:19:41.257000+05:30
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have pytz:

```
tz = pytz.FixedOffset(180)
now = timezone.now()
local_now = tz.normalize(now.astimezone(tz))
```

Answer (score 11):

You have to implement subclass of `datetime.tzinfo` class. General guide is [described here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), where you also can find excellent examples of custom tzinfo implementations.

Here is example (given that there is no daylight saving time) :

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
from pytz import UTC


class MyUTCOffsetTimezone (tzinfo):

    def __init__(self, offset=19800, name=None):
        self.offset = timedelta(seconds=offset)
        self.name = name or self.__class__.__name__

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)


now = datetime.now(tz=UTC)
print now
# -> 2015-01-28 10:46:42.256841+00:00
print now.astimezone(MyUTCOffsetTimezone())
# -> 2015-01-28 16:16:42.256841+05:30
print datetime.now(MyUTCOffsetTimezone())
# -> 2015-01-28 16:16:42.256915+05:30
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, only `import datetime`

```
>>> tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=19800))
```

Next, you can, for example

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(tz).isoformat(timespec='minutes')
'2021-08-03T18:07+05:30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent answer from @Joe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28270767/13320665), I wrote a function which monkey-patches pytz to support named timezones such as 'UTC-06:00' or 'UTC+11:30'.  I can construct one of these names based on an offset sent to me from a browser, which only has an integer given by Javascript new Date().getTimezoneOffset() as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and referenced [here](https://support.maxmind.com/geoip-faq/geoip2-and-geoip-legacy-implementation/how-can-i-determine-the-timezone-of-a-website-visitor/), and then I can post the name as a normal timezone name usable by the rest of my application which uses pytz.

This mechanism would also work for the op in this question who has an offset in seconds.

Example construct tzname using the offset the op has in this question:

```
minutes = offset // 60
tzname = 'UTC%s%02d:%02d' % (
    '-' if minutes < 0 else '+',
    abs(minutes) // 60, abs(minutes) % 60))
```

Example construct tzname using a browser timezone offset returned by
JavaScript new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), which of note has a reversed sign:

```
tzname = (
    'UTC%s%02d:%02d' % (
        '-' if browser_tz_offset > 0 else '+', # reverse sign
        abs(browser_tz_offset) // 60, abs(browser_tz_offset) % 60))
```

Use the named zone to construct a tzinfo object:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone(tzname)  # tzname = e.g. 'UTC-06:00' or 'Europe/Madrid'
localized_now = datetime.now(tz)
```

I call this function during application startup.

```
import re
import pytz
from dateutil import tz as dateutil_tz

def post_load_pytz_offset_timezones_server_wide():

    pristine_pytz_timezone = pytz.timezone

    def extended_pytz_timezone(zone):
        matches = re.match('^UTC([+-])([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])$', zone) if zone else None
        if matches:
            sign = -1 if matches.group(1) == '-' else 1
            minutes = int(matches.group(2)) * 60 + int(matches.group(3))
            tzinfo = dateutil_tz.tzoffset(zone, sign*minutes*60)
        else:
            tzinfo = pristine_pytz_timezone(zone)
    return tzinfo

    pytz.timezone = extended_pytz_timezone
```