# Parsing various timezone offsets

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

There are a lot of things asked and answered about Python and timezones, but I couldn't find an answer; I need to parse following TZ format:
`UTC+0700`. It also could be `GMT+0100` or similar. What is the best way to parse it?

I found only solution with string parsing, but maybe it is possible with famous libs like `pytz` or `dateutil`?

Comment: That's not a time zone, that's a time zone offset.  pytz and dateutil work with time zones.  See [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  (Offsets can be parsed as part of the datetime with `strptime`)  Or were you wanting to parse *just* an offset?  And if so, into what?  A `timedelta` object?

Comment: thanks for the note about timezone offset. 
Yes, the thing is I need to parse it separately and - ideally - get tzinfo object.

Comment: dateutil and pytz both have functions for creating a `tzinfo` with a fixed offset, but you have to parse the string yourself separately.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976063/how-to-create-tzinfo-when-i-have-utc-offset